# Python - How to end routine by probability which updates itself with every 'iteration'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

So I've been working on an adaptation of the Balloon Analogous Risk Task. The gist of it is that the participant gets 30 trials (3 condition, 10 trials per condition) and in each of these trials they can fill a balloon with air by pressing the space bar as often as they want. The larger the balloon, the larger the amount of money they can get. They can cash out at any time, even without filling the balloon with air once (then they receive $0 for this trial).
However, the balloon can also pop.

I would like to design the 3 conditions as follows: In the first condition, balloons have an intial value of 1% to pop when clicking the space bar. In the second and third condition, it should be 2% and 5%, respectively. These probabilities of a balloon popping should apply at the very first moment one presses the space bar and increase by the base rate after every time the space bar is pressed. So for condition 1, it would be 1% before pressing space bar the first time, after that 2%, 3%, etc. The other conditions should be 2%, 4%, 6%, etc. and 5%, 10%, 15%, etc. As I said, these conditional values are already stored in a excel-file I read in with my script.

Do you have an idea how to program this in Python? I am new to Python and my first attempt was directed at the sum of times someone pressed the space bar. It also works, but I would rather have probabilities.

I changed my description due to a very helpful comment below by @shmulvad. It was not clear what I wanted. I hope it's now easier to understand.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, share your sample codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test something with a certain probablity, you can in general do:

```py
import random
rnd_val = random.random()  # Generates a pseudorandom value between 0 and 1
prob = 0.05
print(rnd_val < prob)  # Prints True 5% of times, otherwise False
```

Knowing this, we can accomplish your goal the following way:

```py
MONEY_PER_PUMP = 2
MAX_PUMPS_PER_TRIAL = 10
BASE_RISKS = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05]

total_money = 0
for base_risk in BASE_RISKS:
    n_pumps, risk_of_popping = 0, 0
    while True:
        is_done_with_trial = n_pumps >= MAX_PUMPS_PER_TRIAL
        if not is_done_with_trial and event.getKeys(['space']):
            n_pumps += 1
            risk_of_popping += base_risk
            if random.random() < risk_of_popping:
                break
        elif is_done_with_trial or user_wants_to_exit_early:
            total_money += MONEY_PER_PUMP * n_pumps
            break
```

After the loop exits, `total_money` will contain the amount of money the person playing have won if I have understood you correctly.

Comment: Doesn't apply much here, but in general adding floating point numbers is a little risky, so you may want to use `fractions.Fraction` when calculating `risk_of_popping`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I think this answer is very close to what I need, and way shorter than what I have because you combine money, pumps and the risk of popping. Is it possible on stackoverflow to share .py files? I would like to show you what I've got because it's much more than what you guys advise.

Comment: I would only use `fractions.Fraction` if extreme precision is needed.

Comment: Thank you @shmulvad for your time and effort! I will try and adapt my work to your solution, as it takes so little space as compared to my generated solution!